# Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1982857216) (tried to allocate 43 bytes) in tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf, memory-limit

I am trying to export pdf using **tcpdf**. While doing that I got error:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1982857216) (tried to allocate 43 bytes) in

So I tried (got from SO)

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

But the same error still exist there..

I can't edit the `php.ini` file.

How can I fix this?

My **tcpdf** version is  **4.6.011**

Comment: This lacks information on how you are using tcpdf. Without information I can just guess you have an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: If you can't raise the memory limit (which makes perfect sense for example on a hosting system), then you need to revise your code to be less memory hungry...

Comment: `tried to allocate 43 bytes` - When you see that, then it's most likely an infinite loop somewhere. Raising the memory limit won't work since the loop will just allocate all that memory as well. Show us the code you have instead and we might be able to help.